# Java JUnit Testing

Tags: java, junit

I have never used JUnit testing before.I need to test my code with JUnit.
I have been searching google for all day, but I still don't know how to implement it to my code.
For example, I tested my code with main method.should I remove the main method from my code?
Also, probably due to my mistake ,I could not find an assert method that is related to char variables.
Can anyone help with me about this?

My code is provided below:

```
public class RoversOnMars {

    //Variables
    public int x; // x-coordinate 
    public int y;// y-coordinate
    public String compassPoint; // four cardinal compass point,i.e; North, South, West, East
    public static int xCoor, yCoor; // static variables that represent upper-right coordinates of the plateau

    //No-argument constructor
    public RoversOnMars(){
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        compassPoint = "N";
    }
    // Constructor to set the robotic rover's initial location
    public RoversOnMars(int x, int y, String compassPoint){
        setX(x);
        setY(y);
        this.compassPoint = compassPoint;
    }
    //Accessor method that returns x-coordinate value
    public int getX(){
        return x;
    }
    //Accessor method that returns y-coordinate value
    public int getY(){
        return y;
    }
    //Accessor method that returns compass point value, i.e; North, South, West, East
    public String getCompassPoint(){
        return compassPoint;
    }
    //Mutuator method that sets x-coordinate value
    public void setX(int x){
        this.x = x;
    }
    //Mutuator method that sets y-coordinate value
    public void setY(int y){
        this.y = y;
    }
    //Mutuator method that sets compass point value, i.e; North, South, West, East
    public void setCompassPoint(int number){
        switch(number){
            case 1:
                compassPoint = "N";
                break;
            case 2:
                compassPoint = "S";
                break;
            case 3:
                compassPoint = "W";
                break;
            case 4:
                compassPoint = "E";
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Fatal Error.");
                break;
        }
    }
    // Method that includes the letters 'L' for left,  'R' for right, 'M' for move commands.
    //In case of 'L' or 'R' command, the rover does not move; just spin 90 degrees left or right respectively.
    //'M' command makes the rover to move one grid according to where it faces through
    //The method implements the given instructions to tell the rover how to explore the plateau, and prints the instructions in the end.
    public void CommandLetters(String command){
        for(int i=0; i<=command.length()-1; i++){
            switch(command.charAt(i))
            {
                case 'L':
                    if(getCompassPoint() == "N"){
                        setCompassPoint(3);
                        break;
                    }
                    else if(getCompassPoint() == "E"){
                        setCompassPoint(1);
                        break;
                    }
                    else if(getCompassPoint() == "W"){
                        setCompassPoint(2);
                        break;
                    }
                    else if(getCompassPoint() == "S"){
                        setCompassPoint(4);
                        break;
                    }
                case 'R':
                    if(getCompassPoint() == "N"){
                        setCompassPoint(4);
                        break;
                    }
                    else if(getCompassPoint() == "E"){
                        setCompassPoint(2);
                        break;
                    }
                    else if(getCompassPoint() == "W"){
                        setCompassPoint(1);
                        break;
                    }
                    else if(getCompassPoint() == "S"){
                        setCompassPoint(3);
                        break;
                    }
                    break;
                case 'M':
                    if(getCompassPoint() == "N"){
                        this.y = y+1;
                        break;
                    }
                    else if(getCompassPoint() == "E"){
                        this.x = x +1;
                        break;
                    }
                    else if(getCompassPoint() == "W"){
                        this.x = x-1;
                        break;
                    }
                    else if(getCompassPoint() == "S"){
                        this.y = y-1;
                        break;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Fatal Error.");
                    break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(command);
    }
    //Method to define the upper-right coordinates of the plateau
    public static void setPlateauCoordinate(int a, int b){
        xCoor = a;
        yCoor = b;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't see anything in your code related to testing.. Is there anything?

Comment: that's all of my code.I didn't know I should write it according to testing.how should I modify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really difficult to understand what your code is going to achieve. But it seems you want to test method named '*CommandLetters*'.
There are lot of tutorials on net.

Few are :-
See   [tutorialspoints](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/)

Check [Official JUnit](http://junit.org/)   page detailed help

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JUnit/article.html

Here I am sharing very simple test methods for CommandLetters (though your code need lot of re-factoring) . You can add more test cases and various other [assetions](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Assertions)

```
package com.core.java.testing;  

import org.junit.After;  
import org.junit.Before;  
import org.junit.Test;  

import static org.junit.Assert.*;  

public class RoversOnMarsTest {  

// Method is called before each test case execution  
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {

}

// Method is called after each test case execution
@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {

}

@Test
public void testCommandLettersDefaultConst() throws Exception {
    // default const x=0, y=0 , compass : N
    RoversOnMars roversOnMars = new RoversOnMars();
    roversOnMars.CommandLetters("M");
    assertEquals("Y should be 1", roversOnMars.getY(), 1);
    assertEquals("X should be 1", roversOnMars.getX(), 0);
}

@Test
public void testCommandForWCompass() throws Exception {
    // default const x=0, y=0 , compass : W
    RoversOnMars roversOnMars = new RoversOnMars(23, 23, "W");
    roversOnMars.CommandLetters("M");
    assertEquals("Y should be 23", roversOnMars.getY(), 23);
    assertEquals("X should be 22", roversOnMars.getX(), 22);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I can help address your stated questions. You asked

- **"Should I remove the main method from my code?"** No.  Once you add in Junit you can still run your code the way you've always run it
  (using the main)

  However after you add in Junit you will also be able to run the test
  cases.  you will have 2 ways to run these

  1. Your IDE (eg Eclipse) will give you a way to run just the Junits once you've added them by going to New -> Junit Test Case."
  2. Commandline by specifying a custom test Suite class and a runner.

Once you decide which way you want to do it (ide vs command line) I can help you sort that out easily.

- On to your second question: 
  **I could not find an assert method that is related to char variables. Can anyone help with me about this?**

  This should work for you

  ```
  assertArrayEquals(char[] expecteds, char[] actuals) 
       Asserts that two char arrays are equal.
  ```